# Using Waveshare Raspberry Pi TFT LCD with Arduino Uno

Tags: arduino-uno, lcd, raspberrypi, tft

I have a [3.5 inch Waveshare Raspberry Pi TFT LCD](https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/3.5inch_RPi_LCD_(A)) which uses the XPT2046 Touch Controller. I want to use this LCD screen with my Arduino Uno.

I originally believed something like this was impossible, but then I found out that the XPT2046 Touch Controller is compatible with the Arduino, and a large number of libraries for the same exist. However, I'm not really very sure whether I can use this with my Arduino; the design of the screen I have is slightly different from the ones I've found online, which are supposed to be compatible with an Arduino Uno.

Is it possible for me to use this screen with my Arduino Uno? If so, what would the wiring schematics look like, and would I be able to use libraries like URTouch?

Answer (score 1):

Possibly.

The XPT2046 chip is only for the touch screen, not the LCD.  That will be easy to get going on the Arduino since many many Arduino LCD screens use the same chip.

However, you will need to find out what driver chip the LCD display uses (maybe ILI9488 or HX8357 or something similar), and what pins on the Pi header relate to what function on the display (note: it is probably a 16 bit parallel interface, so uses a lot of pins).

Also note that this only applies to displays that connect *only* to the big 40 pin header. If it uses the FPC display connector you will have no luck trying to use it with an Arduino.

Comment: it is SPI https://www.waveshare.com/product/3.5inch-RPi-LCD-A.htm

Comment: That will be very slow over SPI at that resolution...

Comment: Is there a website where I could find which driver chip the LCD uses? The LCD connects only to the 40 pin header on the RPi, and does not use the FPC display connector. It is a parallel interface of 16 pins each side, you're right.

Comment: I've found some [docs](https://www.waveshare.com/product/3.5inch-RPi-LCD-A.htm) (scroll down to the Interface section) which underlines what each pin on the display does. I probably now can build a circuit, but I have no idea on how to program each pin. Is there any guide which you know of?

Comment: as I write in the first comment, it is SPI. try SPI libraries for displays. and lookup Arduino SPI wiring